# Python 2.7.13 urllib return IOError: [Errno 2] : 'python-data.dr-chuck.net\\comments_42.html'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am a new guy who is trying to learn python on Coursera in a course of Using Python to Access Web Data, but in week 4 I meet a problem even when I was trying to run the sample program as following:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter - ')

html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:

    print 'TAG:',tag
    print 'URL:',tag.get('href', None)
    print 'Contents:',tag.contents[0]
    print 'Attrs:',tag.attrs
```

After I enter the address: `python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html`, it always shows a problem like this:

[image: the result I got]

Since the python file is written as a sample for the course, it can't have a problem. So I try to find the answer on internet, tried to use some proxy to check, but it still cannot work. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you paste the error here?

Comment: Also, can you add a print to show exactly what is typed in? ...and what did you type in?! It looks like you didn't include the `http://` at the front and urllib tried to read the local file system.

Comment: `urllib.urlopen("http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html").read()` works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! Yes you are right! I should add "http://" at the beginning of the address, the reason I didn't do this is in my code the input with "http://" did not give any output, which let me misunderstand it as a bug. But actually the reason is that page does not have any anchor tag at all, which gives an empty result! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [urllib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) states:

> Open a network object denoted by a URL for reading. If the URL **does not have a scheme identifier**, or if it has file: as its scheme identifier, this opens a **local file** (without universal newlines); otherwise it opens a socket to a server somewhere on the network.

Your code is fine, but you are passing an URL without scheme identifier: `python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html`, thus urllib tries to open it locally, which produces an IOError.

Try with `http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.html`, it works.

Comment: Your reply really helps me! Thank you!! I should add "http://" at the beginning of the address, the reason I didn't do this is in my code the input with "http://" did not give any output, which let me misunderstand it as a bug. But actually the reason is that page does not have any anchor tag at all, which gives an empty result! I didn't understand the meaning of anchor tags. Thanks again & best wishes!